# How to mock or substitute Entity Framework context in unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, entity-framework-6, ninject

I would like to unit test a business logic component in one of my projects.

BL:

```
public class CommunicationService
{
    IContext context;

    public CommunicationService()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectConfig());
        context = kernel.Get<IContext>();
    }

    // This creates a file
    public void SomeMethodThatUsesIContext() { ... }
}
```

NinjectConfig:

```
class NinjectConfig : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IContext>().To<CommunicationDbContext>();
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ScheduleTransportOrder_1()
{
    communicationService = new CommunicationService();
    communicationService.SomeMethodThatUsesIContext();
    Assert.IsTrue(...) // file should be created.
}
```

I have another Ninject config in the unit test's project:

```
class FakeNinjectConfig : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IContext>().To<FakeDbContext>();
    }
}
```

And I want this implementation of IContext to be used in the unit test. But it still uses the original, CommunicationDbContext implementation. I believed, when I have another ninject configuration here, that will be loaded to the kernel, but I think now I misunderstood something. Could you help me with that?

Comment: The issue really stems from the fact that you are doing `new StandardKernel(new NinjectConfig())` in your `CommunicationService` constructor. I'm unsure what your logic for this is but effectively you'll never be able to provide a mocked `IContext` to `CommunicationService` with the current code. I'd look at Constructor Injection using Ninject and having the `IContext` automatically injected into `CommunicationService` meaning that you can provide a mocked instance in your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you create kernel using `NinjectConfig` instead of `FakeNinjectConfig` in `CommunicationService` constructor.

```
public class CommunicationService
{
    IContext context;

    public CommunicationService()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectConfig());
        context = kernel.Get<IContext>();
    }
```

**Simple way:**

You can create a new constructor to inject a `NinjectModule` or `StandardKernel`.

```
public CommunicationService (StandardKernel kernel) 
{
    context = kernel.Get<IContext>();
}

public CommunicationService(NinjectModule injectModule):this (new StandardKernel(injectModule))
{
    context = kernel.Get<IContext>();
}

public CommunicationService():this (new NinjectConfig())
{}
```

And in the test you can call the constructor with `FakeNinjectConfig`.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ScheduleTransportOrder_1()
{
    communicationService = new CommunicationService(new FakeNinjectConfig ());
    communicationService.SomeMethodThatUsesIContext();
    Assert.IsTrue(...) // file should be created.
}
```

Or

```
[TestMethod]
public void ScheduleTransportOrder_1()
{
    communicationService = new CommunicationService(new StandardKernel(new FakeNinjectConfig ()));
    communicationService.SomeMethodThatUsesIContext();
    Assert.IsTrue(...) // file should be created.
}
```

**Proper way:**

But in my point of view, you should add the `IContext` as dependency and inject `IContext` resolving `CommunicationService`.

```
public class CommunicationService
{
    IContext context;

    public CommunicationService(IContext _context)
    {
       context = _context;
    }
```

And then, when you create an `CommunicationService` you should use `Get` method of kernel instead of a `new` operator. For example, instead of 
`communicationService = new CommunicationService()` you should use `communicationService = Kernel.Get<CommunicationService>();`

```
[TestMethod]
public void ScheduleTransportOrder_1()
{
    var testKernel = new StandardKernel(new FakeNinjectConfig ());
    communicationService = testKernel.Get<CommunicationService>();
    communicationService.SomeMethodThatUsesIContext();
    Assert.IsTrue(...) // file should be created.
}
```

Or you can inject `IContext` directly

```
[TestMethod]
public void ScheduleTransportOrder_1()
{
    communicationService = new CommunicationService(new FakeDbContext());
    communicationService.SomeMethodThatUsesIContext();
    Assert.IsTrue(...) // file should be created.
}
```